# php сортировка массива по ключу дата

Tags: php, массивы

Как сделать php сортировку массива по ключу дата, т,е по name_client_cdata

```
 stdClass Object
(
    [name_company] => City Format Сити формат
    [id] => 1444
    [manager_id] => 94
    [name_client] => Иванов Андрей Николаевич
    [name_client_email] => 
    [name_client_mobile] => +7 (705) 300-04-53
    [name_client_cdata] => 1987-08-25 00:00:00
)
stdClass Object
(
    [name_company] => ТОО "УРКЕР" 
    [id] => 2018
    [manager_id] => 194
    [name_client] => Сарбулин Галымбет Ахметулы
    [name_client_email] => urker3@mail.ru
    [name_client_mobile] => +7 (777) 928-70-60
    [name_client_cdata] => 1970-08-23 00:00:00
)
stdClass Object
(
    [name_company] => Дизайн Ультра
    [id] => 6724
    [manager_id] => 86
    [name_client] => Виктор
    [name_client_email] => 
    [name_client_mobile] => +7 (701) 904-44-57
    [name_client_cdata] => 1969-08-27 00:00:00
)
```

Comment: @iksuy, касательно usort да, но касательно сравнения дат думаю не идентичен.

Comment: @Kison, я не пишу на php, но что будет при простом сравнении, без приведения с помощью `strtotime`? Учитывая, как в вопросе отформатирована дата - `[name_client_cdata] => 1969-08-27 00:00:00`, если при простом сравнении будет использоваться лексикографическое сравнение строк - то все будет работать корректно.

Comment: Как вы получаете данные?